# How can I get the GridViewEventArgs from an OnTextChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a textbox within a GridView > Column > asp:TemplateField > ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

And the event is fired in code-behind:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

But this TextBox exists for each row in the table, so how can I get the Id for the row that triggered the event?

E.g. for an OnRowEditing event it'd pass `GridViewEditEventArgs` instead of just `EventArgs`

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to `(sender as Textbox).ID` or `(sender as Textbox).Text`, in the `TextBox1_TextChanged` method.

Comment: Do you mean index of row by saying `Id for the row`, or you have hiddenfield etc.. at row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, As far as I understand the question, that is, you want to get the row index that holds your `TextBox` control that fires the change event.
You can do something like this:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)tb.NamingContainer;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);
}
```